# How to list all database collections in MarkLogic?

Tags: nosql, marklogic

I am wondering is it possible to get a database collections list using node.js client?
I have found a way [how to do it](https://www.bigdatamark.com/listing-all-collections-without-a-collection-lexicon/) using XQuery and it works fine in "Query console", but I'm not sure is it possible to run that query from node.js client?

Answer (score 0):

The node.js API supports Structured Queries:
[Node.js Application Developers Guide: Searching with Structured Queries](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_28266)

Structured queries can be used to query collections:
[Search Developers Guide: collection-query](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_76890)

I haven't had a chance to test it, but as long as the [collection lexicon](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/lexicon#id_50782) is enabled, then you should be able to use something like this to get the list:

```
"collection-query": {
  "uri": [ "*" ]
}
```

[Search Developers Guide: Structured Query Overview](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_47703)